# How to work with page breaks in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using a template to write a thesis with the beginning of the thesis (title, acknowledgements, table of contents, etc.) numbered i, ii, iii, etc. For the main text of the thesis, if I wish to print a page, I cannot select it starting at pg. 1 of the main text. Is there a way around this? I would like to select a given number of pages of the main text to print. I thought it was a question of page breaks, hence my title. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert a page break, anywhere in the text where you want to start
a new page, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The text below the break is transferred to a new page. Usually you want to do this after the table of content to ensure that your new page content does not start directly below the table of content, but on a fresh new page.

You are, of course, not limited to just one page break. Every time you want to start a new chapter, you usually want to break the page too, or if you want to ensure that a paragraph remains on one page, you can choose to break before the paragraph to transfer that paragraph to a new page too. This is especially useful in technical documents.

Now, when printing the document, you can select from which pages you want to print to ensure that your text is selected, not the things you don't want before that.